# How can I search with wildcard on Google Search?

Tags: google-search, search-engine

I want to search URLs like this:

- "blablabla.com/a1234568"
- "blablabla.com/a8564654"
- "blablabla.com/a5648979"

So as you can see I want to make a search like this `blablabla.com/a*`

But I can't do this with Google. How can I do this search?

Answer (score 2):

'*' is what you're searching for.

Comment: Do you have an example query where this wildcard would work? I couldn't find one.

Comment: I tried "what a load of *" and it worked.